# How do I configure a block text cursor?

Tags: xfce

Note that I'm not asking about [mouse cursors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343109/large-cursor-xfce) or themes or pointers at all.

I would like a block cursor in XFCE4 text fields—such as the one in which I'm typing right now to ask this question—but all XFCE appears to offer is a thin vertical line. I seem to be able to configure blinking speed via the Keyboard Settings applet, but is there something in GTK or maybe XFCE itself that can be used to achieve a block shape?

Comment: xfce4 uses vte, though generally not the newest version.  vte 0.53 recognizes `DECSCUSER`, according to its source code.  There's no ***documentation*** of course.

Comment: Related: [configuring cursor shapes in gnome](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/622842)

Comment: See also: https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/gtk_theme